# create package can't generate binary

Tags: ros, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,I follow the "Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++)" turtorial to create package,all seem to
have no error, but after the build process, I can't find any binary in the bin folder.The same case also
occur in my eclipse environment.Actually earlier I used diamondback I can successfully do all this.
my ros version is electric .
any suggestion would be appreciate!
thanks in advance!!

> viiv@viiv-ThinkStation-S10:~$ rosmake test
> [ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['test']
> [ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/viiv/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120512-012517
> [ rosmake ] Expanded args ['test'] to:
> ['test']
> [ rosmake ] Checking rosdeps compliance for packages test.  This may take a few seconds.
> [ rosmake ] rosdep check passed all system dependencies in packages
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
> No Makefile in package rosbuild
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
> No Makefile in package roslang
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosparam [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosparam ROS_NOBUILD in package rosparam
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster
> [rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout
> [rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
> No Makefile in package roslaunch
> [rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]
> [rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
> No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
> No Makefile in package rosmsg
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs
> [rosmake-2] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
> [rosmake-2] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
> [rosmake-0] Starting >>> test [ make ]
> [rosmake-0] Finished <<< test [PASS] [ 0.36 seconds ]
> [ rosmake ] Results:
> [ rosmake ] Built 37 packages with 0 failures.
> [ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
> [ rosmake ] /home/viiv/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120512-012517

Edit1
my CMakeLists.txt file content

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
> include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
> > set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)   
> > rosbuild_init()
> > set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
> set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
> rosbuild_add_executable(test src/test.cpp)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33796/create-package-can%27t-generate-binary/) by [David B](https://answers.ros.org/users/2267/david-b/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-05-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-11**:
Have you tried with Fuerte? Or are you limited to electric for some other reason?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-05-11**:
What is in your CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [David B](https://answers.ros.org/users/2267/david-b/) on 2012-05-12**:
I have tried diamondback it's ok!!

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2012-05-13**:
I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not name your target executable **`test`** as this is a special target for CMake to compile and run unittests. If you have no unittests defined, nothing happens. Rename your binary target and try again. Maybe you have to rename your package as well.

---

Originally posted by [Stephan](https://answers.ros.org/users/266/stephan/) with karma: 1924 on 2012-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0